# how to Store Device token getting from HTTPPost web api method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am getting device token from android app through HTTPPOST Web API method. I need to store that token in one variable and that value should be accessable in other API's to send Notifications.

I have controllername: APIController

```
 [HttpPost]
 [api/controller/Token]
 Public HttpResponseMessage POST(string token)
 {
 }
```

How to store the token value globally to access that value in other api's in .net core web API?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Storing one Api's and using it in another Api for notification is kind of violation of [Guiding Principles of REST](https://restfulapi.net/).

```
Stateless – Each request from client to server must contain all of the 
information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of 
any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on 
the client.
```

It would also create problem when load increases and WebApi server needs to scan.
If you need to store token or any data, use external cache component e.g. [Redis](https://redis.io/)